# Whats the best way to inject same instance of service in service for Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

I'va a ServiceImpl with is annotated with @Service stereotype of Spring and have two methods in it each one is annotated with custom annotations which are intercepted by Spring.

```
@Service    
public class ServiceImpl implements Service{

       @CustomAnnotation
       public void method1(){
       ...
       }

       @AnotherCustomAnnotation
       public void method2(){
        this.method1();   
        ...
       }
    }
}
```

Now Spring uses proxy based AOP approach and hence as I'm using `this.method1()` interceptor for @CustomAnnotation will not able to intercept this call, We used to inject this service in another FactoryClass and in that way we were able to get the proxy instance like -

```
  @AnotherCustomAnnotation
    public void method2(){
        someFactory.getService().method1();   
        ...
    }
```

I'm now using Spring 3.0.x, which is the best way to get the proxy instance?

Comment: Can you switch to CGLIb-based class proxies? This should solve the issue.

Comment: @Tomasz: Not, it shouldn't. CGLIB proxies are proxies too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other alternative is to use AspectJ and @Configurable.
Spring seems to be going towards these days (favoring).

I would look into it if you are using Spring 3 as it is faster (performance) and more flexible than proxy based aop.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods are inside the same proxy, whereas the AOP functionality just enriches calls from the outside (see [Understanding AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)). There are three ways for you to deal with that restriction:

1. Change your design (that's what I would recommend)
2. <s>[Change proxy type](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying) from JDK-proxy to proxy-target-class (CGLib-based subclassing)</s> Nope, that doesn't help, see @axtavt's comment, it would have to be static AspectJ compilation.
3. Use `((Service)AopContext.currentProxy()).method1()` (Works, but is an awful violation of AOP, see the end of [Understanding AOP Proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies))

Comment: So I should change my design. just because Spring can't do this?

Comment: @Premraj That's not a question of can't. It doesn't do it, by design. AOP comes from the outside, and method calls within one object must never depend on it. Also, Spring didn't invent the JDK proxy mechanism. Blame Sun, if you want

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd He can do this if he drops proxy based AOP and uses AspectJ. So I don't know if its by design but rather a limitation of proxy aop.

Comment: @Adam true. Maybe they turned the restrictions into a design :-)

Comment: @Sean: Point 2 is completely wrong, CGLIB proxies are proxies too, internal call wouldn't go through them as well.

Comment: @axtavt thanks, I sometimes confuse CGLib proxies with static AspectJ compilation :-)

Comment: @Premraj M: to defend Spring framework, EJB 3 suffers the same issue. But what is considered a bad design in Spring (using `AopContext.currentProxy()`) is a standard and advised approach in EJB ([getBusinessObject()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html#getBusinessObject(java.lang.Class)))

Comment: May be because Objects shouldn't rely on the aspect environment and thats the whole purpose of AOP

Answer (score 0):

You could make your ServiceImpl class implement the [BeanFactoryAware](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactoryAware.html) interface, and lookup itself thanks to the provided bean factory. But this is not dependency injection anymore.

The best solution is to put method1 in another service bean, which would be injected in your existing service bean and to which your existing service bean would delegate.