# Get AOP proxy from the object itself

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Is possible to get the proxy of a given object in Spring? I need to call a function of a subclass. But, obviously, when I do a direct call, the aspects aren't applied. Here's an example:

```
public class Parent {

    public doSomething() {
        Parent proxyOfMe = Spring.getProxyOfMe(this); // (please)
        Method method = this.class.getMethod("sayHello");
        method.invoke(proxyOfMe);
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    @Secured("president")
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello Mr. President");
    }
}
```

I've found a way of achieving this. It works, but  I think is not very elegant:

```
public class Parent implements BeanNameAware {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private String beanName; // Getter

    public doSomething() {
        Parent proxyOfMe = applicationContext.getBean(beanName, Parent.class);
        Method method = this.class.getMethod("sayHello");
        method.invoke(proxyOfMe);
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [Self injection with spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152686/self-injection-with-spring)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This hack is extremely awkward, please consider refactoring your code or using AspectJ weaving. You may feel warned, here is the solution

```
AopContext.currentProxy()
```

[JavaDoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopContext.html#currentProxy()). I blogged about it [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2009/09/spring-aop-riddle-demystified.html) and [here](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.com/2009/08/spring-aop-riddle.html).

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I added <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true" /> in my config. Anyway, I'm reading in order to try it with AspectJ.

Answer (score 16):

`AopContext.currentProxy()` as suggested by Tomasz will work. A more generic solution, that will work outside of the proxied class is to cast the object to `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised` and get `.getTargetSource().getTarget()`

The former (getting the real object from the proxied object) is something that you should not really need. On the other hand getting the target proxy might be useful in some utility class that inspects existing beans in order to add some feature.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a bean post-processor to set a reference to the proxy on the target bean. It moves the Spring-specifics from your beans to a single class.

**Post-Processor**

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class SelfReferencingBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof SelfReferencingBean) {
            ((SelfReferencingBean) bean).setProxy(bean);
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**Context**

Register the post-processor in `applicationContext.xml`.

```
<bean id="srbpp" class="SelfReferencingBeanPostProcessor"/>
```

**Beans**

Each bean must implement `SelfReferencingBean` to tell the post-processor that it needs a reference to the proxy.

```
public interface SelfReferencingBean {
    void setProxy(Object proxy) ;
}
```

Now implement `setProxy` in each bean that needs to call itself through its proxy.

```
public class MyBean implements SelfReferencingBean {
    MyBean proxy;

    @Override
    public void setProxy(Object proxy) {
        this.proxy = (MyBean) proxy;
    }
}
```

You could put this last bit of code into a bean base class if you don't mind casting `proxy` to bean's type when calling methods directly on it. Since you're going through `Method.invoke` you wouldn't even need the cast.

With a little work I bet this could be converted to an annotation processor a la `@Autowired`. Come to think of it, I don't recall if I even tried adding a self-reference using `@Autowired` itself.

```
public class MyBean implements SelfReferencingBean {
    @Autowired MyBean proxy;
}
```