# Spring @Transactional propagation effect of REQUIRES_NEW?

Tags: spring, transactions

I am doing some tests to understand the behaviour of @Transactional in Spring 3. Though, it is not working as I would expect. If have one method with Propagation.REQUIRED calling another with Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, will the second method be able to retrieve from the DB the data inserted by the first method?

EDITED:
I *AM* seeing uncommitted changed in a @Transaction, here is my (nasty looking) code.

```
@Service
public class FeedManager {
   @Autowired
   JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

   @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
   public boolean createFeed(Feed feed, boolean anonymizeIt) {
      String query = "INSERT INTO feed (name, url, is_active) values (?, ?, ?)";
      int rowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(query, feed.getName(), feed.getUrl(), feed.isActive()); 
      boolean success = (rowsAffected == 1); 
      if (anonymizeIt) {
         success = success && this.anonymizeFeedName(feed);
      }
      return success;
   }

   @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
   public boolean anonymizeFeedName(Feed feed) {
      String query = "UPDATE feed set name = ? where name = ?";
      int rowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(query, feed.getName() + (new Date()).toString(), feed.getName());
      boolean success = (rowsAffected == 1);
      return success;
   }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:mrpomario/springcore/jdbc/jdbc-testenv-config.xml")
public class TransactionalTest {
   @Autowired
   FeedManager feedManager;

   Feed feed;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
      feed = new Feed("RSS", "http://www.feedlink.com", true);
   }

   @Test
   public void test_Create()  {
      assertTrue(feedManager.createFeed(feed, false));
   }

   @Test
   public void test_Anonymize() {
      assertTrue(feedManager.anonymizeFeedName(feed));
   }

   @Test
   public void test_Create_And_Anonymize() {
      Feed feedo = new Feed("AnotherRSS", "http://www.anotherfeedlink.com", true);
      assertTrue(feedManager.createFeed(feedo, true));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should not be able to see any changes made by the first method (as long as your isolation level is `READ COMMITTED` or above).

If you get different results, make sure that `@Transactional` actually takes effect. In particular, make sure that you don't call another `@Transactional` method of the same class - due to limitations of Spring proxy-based AOP model transactional aspect is applied only to calls that come from the outside of the class.

**See also:**

- [7.6.1 Understanding AOP proxies](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)

Comment: I agree. That's the behaviour I expected to see given that READ_COMMITED is the default for @Transaction. Though, why am I seeing the uncommited data in the second method?

Comment: The only case when you can see uncomitted changes is when you are inside a transaction that made them. That's why I suspect that the second `@Transactional` doesn't take effect.

Comment: I agree with you, that's what the documentation says but not what I am seeing. I just added my code in which I noticed the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Have you read the second part of my answer? That's exactly the case I tell you about - `@Transactional` doesn't take effect when you call different method of the same class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482666/get-aop-proxy-from-the-object-itself for workarounds.