# Is it possible to use Spring AOP without creating beans?

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

Spring AOP depends on proxy mechanism - J2SE dynamic proxies or using CGLIB(according to the spring documentation). 
Is it possible to use the AOP mechanism defined by Spring without creating/declaring the beans in the spring application context?

If its not possible with Spring - is AspectJ's Load time Weaving(LTW) or Compile Time Weaving (CTW) would help resolve the issue?

Requirement : Trying to implement logging and transaction management for a old project of mine without declaring the POJO's as spring beans.

Comment: spring knows only stuff that comes from a bean factory ...

Comment: Yes ApsectJ is the real thing!

Comment: You can use aspectj and weavers with spring's @Configurable.

Comment: However logging with a framework like log4j would probably be harder because of the timing on classes being loaded.

Comment: [here is a question related to logging by aspects using spring-aop vs aspectj](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19068725/1113392)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Spring can use AspectJ annotations but it will use its own AOP-light mode which only works within its context.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to put them under Spring's control.  You can't ask Spring to advise beans that it doesn't know about.

No calls to "new"; have to replace those with application context.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @duffymo Spring can only operate on beans declared within its context.

AspectJ, both LTW and CTW, can be used to achieve what you want.

Another tools you might consider is [Byteman](https://www.jboss.org/byteman.html), which operate at a lower level but has also a lower overhead if performance is an issue for you.