# Unable to access proxy object in Spring AOP

Tags: spring, spring-aop

This issue might be kind of simple but I just can't find the solution.
I'm using Spring AOP and currently I'm only trying to acquire a reference to a proxy object created by the framework itself. 
I followed the instructions provided by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482666/get-aop-proxy-from-the-object-itself) thread, but I'm still getting the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find current proxy: Set 'exposeProxy' property on Advised to 'true' to make it available.

Here's the required entry in my springContext.xml:

```
 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>
```

This is my aspect definition:

```
@Aspect
public class DynamicAspect {


@Pointcut("execution(* addition.aop.Actor.play(..))")
public void play() {

}

@Before("play()")
public void directorGivesInstructions() {
    System.out.println("Director: Light, camera, action!");
}
```

The main-method where everything gets tested:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
 Actor actor = (Actor) context.getBean("actor");
 actor.play();
}
```

This is the method in the Actor class that raises the exception:

```
 public void play() {
    AopContext.currentProxy();
    System.out.println("Actor starts playing his role...");
}
```

The aspect is weaved in and called properly.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the mistake on my own. The code above works fine. However, swapping the compiler from ajc to javac, I recognized that proxy exposition only works compiling with javac rather the AspectJ compiler. I hope this helps some of you in the future!