# Call different proxyied method from Spring Aspect

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I have two different aspects. How do I ensure that when calling method from one aspect, it will still go through proxy chain?

Here is relevant code:

*Inner* aspect:

```
@Around("withinReplicatedRepository() && entityMethod() && insertMethod()")
public Object trackInsert(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    return trackChange(jp, ChangeType.INSERT, jp.getArgs()[0]);
}
```

*Outer* aspect:

```
@Around("withinReplicatedRepository() && entityMethod() && autoSaveRepository() && saveMethod()")
public Object saveEntity(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    TransactionUtil.ensureTransactional();

    Object entity = jp.getArgs()[0];
    AutoSaveRepository repository = (AutoSaveRepository)jp.getTarget();
    if (repository.exists(entity)) {
        repository.update(entity);
    } else {
        repository.insert(entity);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
AutoSaveRepository<MyEntity> repo = ...;
repo.save(entity);
```

My problem is that jp.getTarget() will return original class, thus repository.insert() will not be captured by trackInsert.

Comment: What is `...` in `AutoSaveRepository<MyEntity> repo = ...;`? Is `AutoSaveRepository` a singleton bean? Then it should be easy to get the bean for this using `getBean(..)`.

Comment: It is not singleton, there are multiple instances of AutoSaveRepository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```java
AopContext.currentProxy()
```

See [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/AopContext.html#currentProxy--).

The prerequisite is that you activate proxy exposure, though:

- In XML you can do this since Spring 3.0.3 via
  `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy expose-proxy="true"/>`.
- In annotation-style config your can do it since 4.3.1 via
   `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true, exposeProxy = true)`,
  see [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html#exposeProxy---)

Comment: I saw that in other threads. But isn't `AopContext.currentProxy()` considered a sort of a _hack_?

Comment: It is documented in Spring's Javadoc. What would you think? But if you have another way of getting hold of the bean instance (proxy), use that one. Alternatively, use full AspectJ with LTW and get rid of Spring's proxies.

Comment: It does feel a little bit like a hack (see this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7482767/353563), but if this is the only way, then I don't have much choice. Ideally, there would be method in ProceedingJoinPoint to get original object, but I understand why is that hard to achieve.

Comment: So because one person in another answer said that it means it is a hack? Actually, Spring AOP does have its limitations. Compared to AspectJ is is rather "AOP lite", but if you do not want to switch, you have to take what is offered. :-)