# Spring @Async ignored

Tags: java, spring

I am having troubles invoking a method asynchronously in Spring, when the invoker is an embedded library receiving notifications from an external system. The code looks as below:

```
@Service
public class DefaultNotificationProcessor implements NotificationProcessor {

    private NotificationClient client;


    @Override
    public void process(Notification notification) {
        processAsync(notification);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void startClient() {
        client = new NotificationClient(this, clientPort);
        client.start(); 
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void stopClient() {
        client.stop();
    }

    @Async
    private void processAsync(Notification notification) {
        // Heavy processing
    }
}
```

The `NotificationClient` internally has a thread in which it receives notifications from another system. It accepts a `NotificationProcessor` in its constructor which is basically the object that will do the actual processing of notifications.

In the above code, I have given the Spring bean as the processor and attempted to process the notification asynchronously by using `@Async` annotation. However, it appears the notification is processed in the same thread as the one used by `NotificationClient`. Effectively, `@Async` is ignored.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Proxies don't work with internal calls. The call to the async method needs to come from a reference to the proxy, not to the actual object.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`@Async` (as well as `@Transactional` and other similar annotations) will not work when the method is invoked via `this`  (on when `@Async` is used for private methods*), as long as you do not use real AspectJ compiletime or runtime weaving.

**the private method thing is: when the method is private, then it must been invoked via `this` - so this is more the consequence then the cause*

So change your code:

```
@Service
public class DefaultNotificationProcessor implements NotificationProcessor {


    @Resource
    private DefaultNotificationProcessor selfReference;


    @Override
    public void process(Notification notification) {
        selfReference.processAsync(notification);
    }


    //the method must not been private
    //the method must been invoked via a bean reference
    @Async
    void processAsync(Notification notification) {
        // Heavy processing
    }
}
```

See also the answers for: [Does Spring @Transactional attribute work on a private method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396284/does-spring-transactional-attribute-work-on-a-private-method) -- this is the same problem

Comment: Is it possible to autowire DefaultNotificationProcessor inside DefaultNotificationProcessor? Or maybe it's possible to do it on class annotated as a Service, cause when I was using Component annotation it didn't work.

Comment: @MarcinErbel have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152686/self-injection-with-spring/5251930#5251930  --- abstract use Spring 4.3 or use `@Resource` instead of `@Autowired`

Comment: If using `@Autowired` you also need `@Lazy` or you'll create a dependency loop.

Comment: @Ralph why do we need the process method here, can't processAsync take care even if there is only one notification ?