# How to catch transaction exceptions in @Async?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions, spring-async

When writing transactional methods with `@Async`, it's not possible to catch the `@Transactional` exceptions. Like `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`, because they are thrown outside of the method itself during eg transaction commit.

Example:

```
public class UpdateService {
    @Autowired
    private CrudRepository<MyEntity> dao;

    //throws eg ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.class, cannot be caught
    @Async
    @Transactional
    public void updateEntity {
        MyEntity entity = dao.findOne(..);
        entity.setField(..);
    }
}
```

I know I can catch `@Async` exceptions *in general* as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyHandler extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {
    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return (ex, method, params) -> {
            //handle
        };
    }
}
```

But I'd prefer to handle the given exception in a different way ONLY if it occurs within the `UpdateService`.

Question: how can I catch it *inside* the `UpdateService`?

Is the only chance: creating an additional `@Service` that wraps the `UpdateService` and has a `try-catch` block? Or could I do better?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [self-injecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152686/self-injection-with-spring) your bean which should work with [Spring 4.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8450). While self-injecting is generally not a good idea, this may be one of the use-cases which are legitimate.

```
@Autowired
private UpdateService self;

@Transactional
public void updateEntity() {
    MyEntity entity = dao.findOne(..);
    entity.setField(..);
}

@Async
public void updateEntityAsync(){
    try {
       self.updateEntity();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // handle exception
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is indeed a valid usecase for self-injection that might be sufficient. The question is: is it?

Comment: @membersound: In my opinion, it is valid. It is also possible to misuse it so that you end up with a "god class" with 1000 lines. But your the exception handling is specific to this class, why not put it in the class. If anyone considers it a bad practise, they could leave a comment here...

Comment: It does not work and fails with: `There is a circular dependency between 1 beans`. spring-boot.1.4.0 with spring.4.2.3

Comment: @membersound: Well it works only with Spring 4.3. Otherwise, according to the link you could try to use `@Resource` and inject by name.

Comment: Sorry typo. I mean: `spring-4.3.2`, so it should work. But does not. But I did not try using `@Resource`, just `@Autowired`. Is it required to use resource injection here? I woudn't want to rely on autowiring by resource service names. Or does `@Autowired` only work when using an interface (I'm just using the class itself)?

Comment: @membersound: autowiring works with classes as well. Maybe there is another problem?

Comment: I don't think there's another problem, because without self-injection the application works already long time in production.

Comment: @membersound  Strange, for me it worked. Maybe you could try a Hello-World-like app with only a few beans to see if it in isolation?