# Getting Hibernate Session inside AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session, dao

I want to create an exception log in the database when an `@Async` operation fails with an exception.

You can see the implementation for `AsyncExecutorConfiguration` and `AsyncExceptionHandler` classes below.

Inside `AsyncExceptionHandler` class, when I call a service that tries to access the database, I am getting: `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncExecutorConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private AsyncExceptionHandler asyncExceptionHandler;

    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 24;
    private static final String THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "AsynchThread-";

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return asyncExceptionHandler;
    }

}

@Component
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Autowired
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        AsyncErrorLog log = new AsyncErrorLog(ex);
        notificationService.saveLogAndNotify(log); // throws exception "Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread"
    }
}


@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    @Override
    @Async
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doSomething(Long id) {
        // I can execute database operations here

    }
    ...
```

`@Async` function itself already has a valid session. What should I do to have a valid session in `AsyncExceptionHandler` class too?

--

**UPDATE**

Here is the simplified implementations for `NotificationServiceImpl` and `LogDaoImpl.class` where we get the error.

```
@Service
public class NotificationServiceImpl implements NotificationService {

    @Autowired
    private LogDao logDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false)
    public void saveLogAndNotify(Log log) {
        return logDao.createLog(log);
    }


@Repository
public class LogDaoImpl{

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void createLog(Log log) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(log);
    }
```

Comment: would you please share `NotificationServiceImpl` class

Comment: @Spara: `NotificationServiceImpl` calls `LogDaoImpl` where we get the error. I shared the implementation for that class.

Comment: Did you try to add `@Transactional` top of `LogDaoImpl` class?

Comment: We have `@Transactional` at the service level at `NotificationServiceImpl` and it is being called from a lot of places in the application without any problems except for the `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`. (Updated the code to show the service implementation)

Comment: Yeah I see, but the error means that your service layer could not start a transaction successfully, I tried to make your situation on my project but I couldn't maybe because I used spring data, Please change 2 things and tell me does it works or not: First please change `@Component` to `@Service` in the `AsyncExceptionHandler` class and second please add `@Transactional` at the `LogDaoImpl`

Comment: @Spara Still same error. I suspect the problem is with how https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.2.x/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java class handles the exception.

Comment: Maybe you should handle this by your own, I have a solution for it, I will add it as an answer, would you please check it works or not?

Answer (score 3):

Per the Hibernate exception; if you're not using Spring Data, you'll have to make sure the notification service explicitly invokes the database calls on the Hibernate session.

On another note, in my experience, the main use cases for the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` (in general) are used for:

1. A simple last-resort to handle `RuntimeException`s that may be unknown to the programmer that for some reason cannot (or are not) caught in code
2. A way to catch exceptions in code that the programmer has no control over (e.g. if you're invoking Async directly on some third party library, etc.)

The commonality between the two is that this `Handler` is used for something unexpected. In fact, Spring itself accounts for the "unexpectedness" in your own code and Spring Async *already* [sets a default one for you that will log to the console](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.html) (code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.java)), letting you not have to worry about rogue exceptions killing threads and not knowing why. (Note: The message in the source code says it's catching an "unexpected" exception. Of course exceptions are unexpected, but these are one's that you **really** didn't know could happen. Spring Async will log it for you.)

That being the case, in your example, since you're doing Spring Database operations and should know exactly what's happening inside of `#doSomething`, I would just go with removing the AUEH a `try-catch` (and/or `-finally`) and handle the exception inside of `#doSomething`:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    // Self autowired class to take advantage of proxied methods in the same class
    // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922604/transactional-and-stream-in-spring/51923214#51923214
    private MyService myService;  

    private NotificationService notificationService;  

    @Override
    @Async
    public void doSomething(Long id) {
        // I can execute database operations here
        try {
            myService.doDatabaseOperations(...);
        } catch(DatabaseAccessException e) {
            AsyncErrorLog log = new AsyncErrorLog(ex);
            notificationService.saveLogAndNotify(log);
        }
        // Other exceptions (from DB operations or the notifications service) can be 
        // handled with other "catches" or to let the SimpleAsyncExHandler log them for you.
        // You can also use standard multithreading exception handling for this
    }

    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void doDatabaseOperations(...) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @Dovmo, can you elaborate on "if you're not using Spring Data, you'll have to make sure the notification service explicitly invokes the database calls on the Hibernate session."  We are not using Spring Data, how do I make sure that the notification service explicitly invokes the database calls on the Hibernate session?

Comment: Your implementation is very close to how we solved the problem right now but we have to repeat the same try/catch block in every @Async implementation. It would be nicer if we could handle them all in one place.

Comment: I'm envisioning two ways for you to modularize things: (1) Have an AOP/Intercepter annotation or (2) You can have `doSomething` return a `CompletableFuture` for that `@Async` call. You can have your service accept the exception from `CompletableFuture`'s `#exceptionally` and invoke the DB logger. Do either of those make sense or need explanation?

Comment: Yes, they make sense to me. We are still using Java7, therefore CompletableFuture is not an option. But I can see opportunities to remove the try/catch block duplication, once I remove my focus away from AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `applicationContext` in your handler to lookup the `notificationService`. I had the same issue when I used `@Autowired` for the handler, which in turn injected my `LogService`. After looking at the logs I saw that the `TransactionSynchronizationManager` is clearing transaction synchronization after the rollback of the exception and nothing else except the `no transaction for ......` error.

After using the `applicationContext` for looking up the `logService` bean and changing my handler, I saw the desired result in the logs.

1. begin
2. Initializing transaction synchronization
3. Getting transaction for [....AsyncService.doAsync]
4. Exception
5. rolling back
6. Clearing transaction synchronization
7. **begin**
8. **Initializing transaction synchronization**
9. **Getting transaction for [.....LogService.save]**

Change your config to include the interface `ApplicationContextAware` which will give you a convenience method to access the `applicationContext`. Set it as a instance variable.

See my configuration class below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 3;
    private static final int QUEUE_CAPACITY = 24;
    private static final String THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "AsynchThread-";

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(CORE_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(QUEUE_CAPACITY);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX);
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return new AsyncExceptionHandler(this.applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

I have removed the `@Component` from the handler and use it as a POJO.
Every time `getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` is called with an exception, a new handler instance is created with the `applicationContext` as a dependency.

```
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public AsyncExceptionHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        Log log = new Log();
        log.setEntry(ex.getMessage());
        LogService logService = this.applicationContext.getBean(LogService.class);
        logService.save(log);
    }
}
```

The `save` method on `logService` requires a new transaction every time it is called.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void save(Log log)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you:

```
@Override
public void createLog(Log log) {
try {
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}
    session.saveOrUpdate(log);
}
```

Comment: Hi Spara, this solution does not complain about the session but does not commit the transaction either. We could go on and try to commit the transaction but I prefer Spring @Transactional handling all this process instead of manual intervention.

Comment: @nilgun Yes you are right, this is the last solution that if you didn't know what to do you can use it...