# What's the "Right Way" to send a data changed websocket event and ensure the database is committed in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket

**Note: read the end of the answer for the way I implemented @Nonika's suggestions**

What's the "right way" to send a websocket event on data insert?

I'm using a Spring Boot server with SQL/JPA and non-stomp websockets. I need to use "plain" websockets as I'm using Java clients where (AFAIK) there's no stomp support.

When I make a change to the database I need to send the event to the client so I ended up with an implementation like this:

```java
@Transactional
public void addEntity(...) {
     performActualEntityAdding();
     sendEntityAddedEvent(eventData);
}

@Transactional
public void sendEntityAddedEvent(String eventData) {
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            sendEntityAddedEventAsync(eventData);
        }
    });
}

@Async
public void sendEntityAddedEventAsync(String eventData) {
    // does the websocket session sending...
}
```

This works. If I would just call the `sendEntityAddedEventAsync` it would also work for real world scenarios but it fails on unit tests because the event would arrive before transaction commit. As such when the unit test invokes a list of the entities after the event it fails.

This feels like a hack that shouldn't be here. Is there a better way to ensure a commit? 
I tried multiple alternative approaches and the problem is that they often worked for 10 runs of the unit tests yet failed every once in a while. That isn't acceptable.

I tried multiple approaches to solve this such as different transaction annotations and splitting the method to accommodate them. E.g read uncommitted, not supported (to force a commit) etc. Nothing worked for all cases and I couldn't find an authoritative answer for this (probably common) use case that wasn't about STOMP (which is pretty different).

**Edit**

One of my original attempts looked something like this:

```java
// this shouldn't be in a transaction
public void addEntity(...) {
     performActualEntityAdding();
     sendEntityAddedEvent(eventData);
}

@Transactional
public void performActualEntityAdding(...) {
     //....
}

@Async
public void sendEntityAddedEventAsync(String eventData) {
    // does the websocket session sending...
}
```

The assumption here is that when `sendEntityAddedEventAsync` is invoked the data would already be in the database. It wasn't for a couple of additional milliseconds.

A few additional details:

- Test environment is based on h2 (initially I mistakenly wrote hsql)
- Project is generated by JHipster
- Level 2 cache is used but disabled as NONE for these entities

**Solution** (based on @Nonika's answer):

The solution for me included something similar to this:

```java
public class WebEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    private ServerEventDAO event;
    public WebEvent(Object source, ServerEventDAO event) {
        super(source);
        this.event = event;
    }

    public ServerEventDAO getEvent() {
        return event;
    }
}


@Transactional
public void addEntity(...) {
     performActualEntityAdding();
     applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new WebEvent(this, evtDao));

}

@Async
@TransactionalEventListener
public void sendEntityAddedEventAsync(WebEvent eventData) {
    // does the websocket session sending...
}
```

This effectively guarantees that the data is committed properly before sending the event and it runs asynchronously to boot. Very nice and simple.

Comment: Also you can use `try` and `catch` for checking if the data was committed or not, if not then an implementation of `PersistenceException` should be thrown, also if you are using `hibernate` then might implement a `listener after saved`. Then based your question is very own of a software developer, No "Right way".

Comment: The request happens asynchronously from the client. It would be surprising to me if there's no officially sanctioned way to implement such a use case.

Comment: So far I know, there is no officially sanctioned way to implement such a use case, using `STOMP` would be the closest one.

Comment: The unit tests sound like the problem. What do they look like? Also, why is `sendEntityAddedEvent` marked as `@Transactional`?

Comment: We need it to be transnational so the  `registerSynchronization` call will work. I tried various combinations of method calls where the parent method isn't transactional and it invokes the save method which is transactional then invokes a separate non-transactional event method. Surprisingly this didn't work. The tests are completely external and work with the webservice/websocket. The problem with them is that they are fast. With the current setup they work so I'm pretty sure the problem was in the server.

Comment: The transaction from `addEntity` should be active when it calls `sendEntityAddedEvent`. It sounds like your transaction boundaries are wrong. Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question with some more details of the original approach I tried which AFAIK **should** work but didn't.

Comment: Are addEntity() and performActualEntityAdding()  in the same class file? if so this way @Transactional on performActualEntityAdding() will not work.

Comment: I used separate session beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring is using `AdviceMode.PROXY` for both `@Async` and `@Transactional` this is quote from the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html#mode--):

> The default is AdviceMode.PROXY. Please note that proxy mode allows
>   for interception of calls through the proxy only. Local calls within
>   the same class cannot get intercepted that way; an Async annotation on
>   such a method within a local call will be ignored since Spring's
>   interceptor does not even kick in for such a runtime scenario. For a
>   more advanced mode of interception, consider switching this to
>   AdviceMode.ASPECTJ.

This rule is common for almost all spring annotations which requires proxy to operate.

Into your first example, you have a @Transactional annotation on both addEntity(..) and performActualEntityAdding(..). I suppose you call `addEntity` from another class so @Transactional works as expected. process in this scenario can be described in this flow

```
// -> N1 transaction starts

addEntity(){             
    performActualEntityAdding()//-> we are still in transaction N1
    sendEntityAddedEvent()  //  ->  call to this @Async is a class local call, so this advice is ignored. But if this was an async call this would not work either.
}
//N1 transaction commits;
```

That's why the test fails. it gets an event that there is a change into the db, but there is nothing because the transaction has not been committed yet.

Scenario 2.

When you don't have a `@Transactional addEntity(..)` then second transaction for `performActualEntityAdding` not starts as there is a local call too.

Options:

- You can use some middleware class to call these methods to trigger
  spring interceptors.
- you can use   [Self injection with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152686/self-injection-with-spring)

  if you have Spring 5.0 there is handy `@TransactionalEventListener(phase = TransactionPhase.AFTER_COMMIT)`

Comment: Thanks. These were in separate beans though, sorry for not clarifying that. The events are fired from an EventSession bean. I'm not sure how I can apply the `TransactionalEventListener`, the docs are a bit unclear here. Can I just annotate the `sendEntityAddedEvent` with `TransactionalEventListener` and then remove the inner class to invoke the async method directly?

Comment: Check this article https://panlw.github.io/15459049161482.html

Comment: I have one question does your test environment use embedded hsql? or dedicated one?

Comment: Thanks, this took a bit of experimentation but it seems to work nicely with `TransactionalEventListener` and it's much more elegant. I'll edit my question with my current code for reference